# Function left with function As

Tags: sql, vba

```
SELECT Left(Code,3) As Code, Count(Left(Code,3)) As CPC 
INTO newtable 
FROM TEST  
GROUP BY Left(Code,3)
```

And second:

```
SELECT Left(Code,3), Count(Left(Code,3)) As CPC 
INTO newtable 
FROM TEST  
GROUP BY Left(Code,3)
```

Hi I have problem with this codes. First isnt work, but second yes, I think that problem is in that **Left()** with **As** can anyone help me how to fix it ? thanks :-)

Comment: Why the vba tag? What kind of database (MS-SQL?) In MSSQL I do not see any problem with using the left in combination with as. It may help to put it like this: As [Code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use different alias name

```
SELECT Left(Code,3) As Code_new, Count(Left(Code,3)) As CPC 
INTO newtable 
FROM TEST  
GROUP BY Left(Code,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you don't have a `column name` for your first column. You need to give some name you cannot create a table without a column name

```
SELECT Left(Code,3) as L_CODE, Count(Left(Code,3)) As CPC 
INTO newtable 
FROM TEST  
GROUP BY Left(Code,3)
```